# How do I jump to the matching tag, when editing HTML in Emacs?

Tags: html, emacs

Suppose I'm editing a very long and messy HTML file. With my cursor at an open tag, is there a way to jump to its closing tag?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming you're using nxml-mode:

```
C-M-n runs the command nxml-forward-element, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `nxml-mode.el'.

It is bound to C-M-n.

(nxml-forward-element &optional ARG)

Move forward over one element.
With ARG, do it that many times.
Negative ARG means move backward.
```

Comment: Incidentally this is the same binding as you'd use to navigate closing/opening parenthesis/brackets/braces in many language modes.

Answer (score 65):

And if you're using `sgml-mode` or its derivatives (e.g. `html-mode`):

`sgml-skip-tag-forward` is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ``sgml-mode.el'`.

It is bound to

`C-c C-f`

or

`C-c <right>`

and bound to the menu bar:

```
<menu-bar> <sgml> <sgml-skip-tag-forward>`
```

From emacslisp:

```
(sgml-skip-tag-forward arg)
```

Skip to end of tag or matching closing tag if present. With prefix argument arg, repeat this arg times. Return t if after a closing tag.

Comment: Conveniently, these functions are written to work regardless of the mode (provided that the `sgml-mode` library has been loaded); so if you use some other mode for editing HTML, you can still call `sgml-skip-tag-forward` and `sgml-skip-tag-backward`.

Comment: And C-c C-b is when you want to jump backwards.

Comment: You have to be BEFORE or IN the <tag> declaration in order for this to work.  If your cursor is positioned at the end of the <tag>X, right after the closing >, the system treats it as being "before" the next subtag, and so jumps only to the end of that next subtag.

Comment: For forward <tags>.  Conversely, if you're positioned right after the END of a closing tag </tag>X, it WORKS to go _backwards_; as jumping backwards applies to *after* or *in* the _first previous_ </tag> found.  It makes sense after you figure it out and get used to it.

Answer (score 15):

...and if you're using [web-mode](http://web-mode.org) <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-n</kbd> will jump from an opening tag to the corresponding closing tag. The mode also has some other features (code folding, auto-closing HTML tags, ...) that might be worth taking a look at.