# Jump to matching django template tag in emacs?

Tags: django, emacs

Emacs has a feature that allows one to [jump to matching HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468111/how-do-i-jump-to-the-matching-tag-when-editing-editing-html-in-emacs).  You position your cursor on an opening `<div>`, say, then press `C-c <right arrow>`, and the cursor jumps to the corresponding closing `</div>` tag.

Is there any equivalent functionality specifically for Django template tags?  For example, I want to position the cursor on an opening `{% if %}` tag, and then run an emacs command that moves the cursor to the corresponding `{% endif %}` tag.

Is there any equivalent functionality for defining arbitrary open/close syntax, so that arbitrary file formats can be accommodated?

I notice that since I posted this question, [web-mode](http://web-mode.org/) has been developed and become popular.  It appears that that mode attempts to provide this feature, but I have not found the emacs command that does so (perhaps because I don't know how to select the correct "family" for the django template language?).

Answer (score 1):

Looks unmaintained, but have you tried the options [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Emacs)?